# Laravel showing: "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 6 bytes" when table column is empty

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, serialization

I have a table(books) with column named(genre) with serialize array.

when I show the page using

```
public function show($id)
{
    $books = Book::findOrFail($id);
    return view('books.show')->with('books', $books);
}
```

if the table column has array it will display the data.
if the column is empty it should display "empty"
but whenever the column is empty it will throw error "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 6 bytes".

```
 @if(!empty($books->genre))
     <dt class="font-weight-bold">Genre:</dt>
         <dd>-
             @foreach (unserialize($books->genre) as $item)
                  <span class="pr-3">{{ $item }}</span>
             @endforeach
         </dd>
  @else
       <h1>Empty</h1>
  @endif
```

I also have trie using isset() and is_array() instead of !empty() and still it failed.

Comment: So, this means that `$books->genre` is __not__ empty. `var_dump` value.

Comment: You really need to normalise your database tables

Comment: yeah thanks, i agree i should learn how to normalize Db. I fix it by adding if(is_array()) and change !empty() with count().